# SCons - how to provide explicit dependency for targets across scripts

Tags: dependencies, code-generation, scons

This is my main SConstruct file

```
env = Environment()

gen_source = env.SConscript(
        'generate_sources.scons',
        variant_dir='derived_src', src_dir='src',
        duplicate=0)
compile_source = env.SConscript('compile.scons',
        variant_dir='build', src_dir='derived_src',
        duplicate=0)
env.Depends('build/', 'derived_src/')
```

The `gen_source` is a script with one source generator target which outputs files in `derived_src/` from my source directory, and `compile_source` is a script with multiple targets.

If no target is provided in command line, i.e. run `scons`, it will generate sources then compile, but if a target is provided, such as `scons pg_test` then scons will fail and complain about `derived_src/some_file` does not exist.

What is the best way to model such a relationship of targets? Preferably I hope to change its behaviour such that it only generates the sources that are going to be compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you are returning from the gen_source and compile_source SConscript executions, if its a list of targets then I think it would make more sense to setup the dependencies like this:

```
env.Depends(compile_source, gen_source)
```

Or if you're not returning a list of targets, then at the very least, put the directories relative to the root SConstruct, like this:

```
env.Depends('#build', '#derived_src')
```

And one step further would be to specify the files in those directories, possibly with Glob()

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've found a way to `Export()` my generated source file nodes and `Import()` these in my compile.scons file, which is working as expected with the correct dependencies set up. Thank you!